# What is the preferred AngularJS way of adding CSS styling after Controller asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, node-webkit, nw.js

I am building an application with NW.js and AngularJS [GitHub Link](https://github.com/yousefm87/FileVisualizer)

My application retrieves file names from local folders and displays these filenames in the application as a list. I want the first item in the list look different from the rest because it starts as the "selected" button/item. The file data is asynchronous.

Currently, I have the file data loaded as a service which pulls the file names inside of the controller. Because the file data uses an asynchronous function, I have placed this within a async.series call within the controller. After this async call finishes, the ng-bind takes effect and the list is displayed in my app.

I have tried adding different directives to add the selected class to the first item but they all get called before the list is shown on the screen.

Can someone help me understand what is the preferred angularjs way of setting classes or css properties of an element after it has been binded to the data?

Below is the relevant code. For the full project follow the GitHub link above.

### Controller

```
fileVizApp.controller("fileVizController", function ($scope, configs, consoles, $location) {
    var async = require('async');
    var filehelper = require('filehelper');

    var consoleKeys = [];

    for(var key in consoles) {
        consoleKeys.push(key);
    }

    async.each(consoleKeys, function(currConsole, callback) {
        filehelper.GetItemList(consoles, currConsole, callback);

        var a = 9;
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        $scope.headerSrc = "tmpl/header.html";

        $scope.configs = configs;


        $scope.back = function () {
            window.history.back();
        };

        $scope.getCount = function (n) {
            return new Array(n);
        }

        $scope.isActive = function (route) {
            return route === $location.path();
        }

        $scope.isActivePath = function (route) {
            return ($location.path()).indexOf(route) >= 0;
        }

        $scope.$apply( function () {
            $scope.consoles = consoles;
             if(consoles.length > 0) {
                $scope.currConsoleInd = 0;
                if(consoles.length > 1) {
                    $scope.nextConsoleInd = 1;
                    $scope.prevConsoleInd = consoles.length - 1;
                } else {
                    $scope.nextConsoleInd = -1;
                    $scope.prevConsoleInd = -1;
                }

            }
            else {
                $scope.nextConsoleInd = -1;
                $scope.prevConsoleInd = -1;
            }

        });


        $scope.$broadcast("Consoles_Ready");
    });

});
```

### Relevant HTML

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="fileVizApp">

<head>
    <title>File Visualizer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.0.min.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/service/services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/router/routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directive/directives.js"></script>    
</head>

<body class="container" data-ng-controller="fileVizController" main-directive>
    <div data-ng-include src="headerSrc"></div> 
    <div id="container">
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


<!-- home.html-->

<div class="">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <ym-gamelist/>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
</div>


<!-- itemlist.html -->

<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <div ng-repeat="thisConsole in consoles">
            <div ng-repeat="item in thisConsole.items" button-repeat>
                <li>
                    <a class="itembutton" href="#"><span ng-bind="item"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Directives

```
fileVizApp.directive('ymGamelist', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'fileVizController',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on('Consoles_Ready', function () {
            var newa = 1;
        });

    },
    compile: function (element, attrs) { 
        return {
            pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
                console.log(name + ': pre link => ' + iElem.html());
            },
            post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
                console.log(name + ': post link => ' + iElem.html());
            }
        }
    },
    templateUrl: 'tmpl/itemlist.html'
  };
});

fileVizApp.directive('buttonRepeat', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if(scope.$last) {
        scope.$emit('Itemlist_Loaded');
      }
  };
});

fileVizApp.directive('mainDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$on('Itemlist_Loaded', function (event) {
        $('.gamebutton').first().addClass('selectedbutton');
      });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$first` variable available inside `ng-repeat` together with `ng-class` to do this. Something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in thisConsole.items" button-repeat>
                <li>
                    <a class="itembutton" href="#" ng-class={'selectedbutton':$first}><span ng-bind="item"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a followup question. 

I want to add event listeners the keyboard (and later gamepad) after all the binding has occured and the elements are visible on the screen. My directives seem to run before the elements become visible on the screen. 

Do you know how to ensure the data binded and the elements are loaded before setting event listeners?

Comment: In angular there is no effective way to know when UI rendering is complete. The best way is the put some timeout using $timeout service.